# Done function is never executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having problems with one of my javascript functions. throughout my webpage i have multiple  `$.ajax` calls followed by `.done()` and they all seem to work, except one. Can someone spot error?

```
me.AcquireProject = function (lnkClicked) {
    myheader = lnkClicked.closest('th');
    // Get text from cell
    var headerTxt= myheader.clone().children().remove().end().text()

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "UpdateProperties.aspx",
        data: {
            action: "UpdateProject",
            projectId: headerTxt
        }
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        myheader.append('<span class="label label-info pull-right"> TEST: Ajax call is completed </span>')
    })
}
```

debugging using VS2010 & Firefox-firebug  showed that the `ajax-call` is executed `without fault`.  But `my debugpoint @myheader.append... is never reached`.

**Question**: What could be the reason for it to skip the done() part?

**Note:** As i'm still a 'beginner', don't be afraid to criticise my Jquery usage. I'm open (even requesting) for improvements.

Comment: ok you said that your ajax is being executed (checkek with firebug). But, does it return any data? in proper format? 
Also, is it possible you get an undefined error on your  myheader = lnkClicked.closest('th'); ?

Comment: The function originates from a click in a tableheader. So in theory there is always a `th` but you're right. An extra check is desirable. The ajax itself doesn't return any data (yet). But even when i do `.done(function () { } )` then the `done()` still isn't being executed.

Comment: Replace the append call with a basic `console.log("success")` to simplify. If that doesn't show in the console, add a `.fail()` handler and see if that fires. `.done` is the success function, it will only execute if there's no errors (unlike `complete` or `always`).

Comment: did you try to add `.fail(console.log.bind(console))`

Comment: Both fail & error are being reached.So something goes wrong (obivously). Is there a way to catch the actual error message?

Comment: `.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { console.log(errorThrown); })`

Comment: @N55PEC clarification please. You said "The ajax itself doesn't return any data (yet)". The page UpdateProperties.aspx does exist though, yes?

Comment: Yes! But for now the action `UpdateProject` only performs an update of a record in the database (which) works. Next (once this part fully works) i want it to return data for the user. But I have found the error. I assumed (incorrectly) that the return of an empty String (As Response.Write) would be ignored by the ajax call. In fact it tries to compile it: hence the error. Many Many thanks to everyone for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With many,many thanks to [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/701961/andrew),[MrCode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995579/mrcode),[EaterOfCode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1283772/eaterofcode) I managed to resolve the issue and save me quite some time!

The problem didn't lie with the code, the exception/error just wasn't caught. 
I added an `.error()-clause` as suggested:

```
$.ajax({...})
.error(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { console.log(errorThrown); })
.done( function() {... })
```

Console showed an error in the return of the ajax-call. I assumed (wrongly) that an `Empty String` is `a`valid response` and would be ignored. When i removed the empty string, then the error did no longer occur.

Comment: An empty string is a valid response. Are you outputting an JSON or XML content type header? If so, jQuery will try to parse the response as JSON and throw the error. You can tell jQuery to not try to parse the response by setting the `dataType : 'text'` or html.

Comment: Indeed the `content type header` was `JSON`. But thanks for the tip for `datatype: 'text'`! It will come in handy!

Comment: It may be helpful to folks new to promises who reach this question/answer to note that any function called which chains into `.done()` must also return a promise before that `.done()` can be called. E.g.:

`myFunc().done()`

Here, `myFunc()` must return a promise in order for `done()` to be called after `myFunc()`s completion.